# Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varchar is not allowed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm getting this error when calling a stored procedure from .NET Entity Framework using Dapper.

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varchar is not allowed.

The stored procedure parameter is `@Name nvarchar(50) = NULL`.

So ideally, it should accept a null value. When I call the stored procedure and pass `@Name = null` from .NET, I get gives this error.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Member_Add]
    @Id NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL,
    @Name NVARCHAR(50)  = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].Member (Id, Name)
    VALUES (@Id, @Name)
END
```

Comment: **SP parameter is @Name nvarchar(50) = NULL. So ideally, it should accept a null value.** : You're wrong here. It makes `@Name` parameter optional and if you don't pass `@Name` it will assign `NULL` value and won't throw exception. You can always pass `NULL` value to parameter.

Comment: @Karan edited. I know I can pass NULL and I've never seen this error before I passed NULL a lot of times.

Comment: Your code is using a parameter of datatype sql_variant when it should be using varchar. Which might look like datatype 'object'.

Comment: @DaleK how it might look like datatype object? what is sql_variant?

Comment: @KinjalParmar I don't know, as I am not familiar with dapper, hence why you will need to post enough code to explain your dapper config for this SP in order for anyone to assist you. Please read [MRE].

Comment: Another question, but you've tagged Dapper and Entity-Framework - surely you're not using both?

Comment: @KinjalParmar Well, you are probably mapping a `DBType.object` to a SQL variant. So you're trying to pass all the parameters as SQL_variants to your SP and when one won't convert, you will get this error. Please show us how you are calling your SP from EF ?

Comment: Sorry you're getting downvoted, I ended up here after much Googling having the EXACT same problem.  Trying to pay attention to a few too many things, I totally missed that I had nulls that dapper was trying to map... and failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dapper was internally mapping `object` to `sql_variant`. When I pass `null` it was considering it as `object` type. As my *stored procedure* was expecting `varchar`, `sql_variant` was not convertible to it.

I started passing `string.Empty` instead of `null` object and it was working fine.

> @Name = Request.Name??string.Empty;

Comment: Yeah I guessed that was happening. You should have shown us how you were calling your S.P. Anyways glad you got this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I had autogenerated my DTO class using Visual Studio's 'Paste Special'->'Paste JSON as classes' and it had set the datatype for some members as object instead of string.